# HABTM not working - unknown bind

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I created three models:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :permissions
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
end
```

and a migration as following:

```
class Changetable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :permissions_roles, id: false do |t|       
        t.belongs_to :permissions      
        t.belongs_to :roles
    end
  end
end
```

And that leeds to following schema.rb which looks exactly the same in my sql database:

```
  create_table "permissions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "subject_class"
    t.string   "subject_id"
    t.string   "action"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "permissions_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "permissions_id"
    t.integer "roles_id"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Now when I call Roles.first.permissions I got following error message:

```
irb(main):001:0> Role.first.permissions
  ←[1m←[36mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mUSE [rails_confreport_develop]←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mRole Load (2.0ms)←[0m  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [roles].* FROM [roles] ORDER BY [roles].[id] ASC'
RuntimeError: Unknown bind columns. We can account for this.
```

Same happens if I call `Permission.first.roles`! What am I missing?

Best regards!

Comment: not sure but google gives link to [activerecord-sqlserver-adapter issues](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/issues/118). What DB do you use?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL and the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter! I will have a look at the link. Thank you!

Comment: If it is not critical for your APP maybe you can change DB on MySQL or Postgres...

Comment: Change to sqlite3 database and the same happened. But maybe I get the error. My foreign ids on `permissions_roles`-table are having a `s`! I will change it real quick and see what happens! Edit: Yep, thats it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was the spelling of the foreign keys in my joined-table.

Changed this:

```
  create_table "permissions_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "permissions_id"
    t.integer "roles_id"
  end
```

to this:

```
  create_table "permissions_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "permission_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end
```

And it works.